# Iframe redirect page in main page

Tags: html, iframe, redirect

I have an iframe page(say page2) in main page(say page1). Also have an iframe page(say page3) inside page2 . Now i want to load the pages in page1  when links clicked in  page3 not in page2.

How to do this ?
Note : All pages are in same domain but page3 is also containing external link. Page load should happen in page1 if something is clicked in page3

Comment: All iframe pages belong to Same domain or not ?

Comment: Page3 is also containing external link

Comment: page 1 and 2 are your domain, and 3 is not your domain ?

Comment: Page3 is my domain. but contains external links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To what i understand, this should help :

```
Page #1
<iframe src='2.html' id=i1 ></iframe>

Page #2
<iframe src='3.html' ></iframe>

Page #3
<a href='#' onclick='top.document.getElementById("i1").src="3.html"'>Test</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your browser requirements, maybe the HTML5 postMessage API could be of use?

Edit: Cross-browser issues could be minimized by using this plug-in: [jQuery PostMessage](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-postmessage-plugin/)